# Create MySQL Trigger manually using VB.NET Application (Systax Error)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, triggers, mysql-workbench, database-trigger

I'm new with MySQL Triggers.
I would like to create MySQL Triggers programmatically using my VB.NET Application so first I create a query using MySQL Workbench test it and it was a success but when I copied the query to my VB.NET Application and put it on string variable and tried to execute it. the error pops up that I have a Syntax error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `updateProductPrice`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `list_events`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.caption <> OLD.caption
    THEN
      SET NEW.caption = 1;
  END IF ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Try not setting delimiters..

Comment: Please provide the error in text, not in an image.

Comment: It worked! I just remove the Delimeter as you told me, I'm getting syntax Error on my Workbench but in my VB.NET Application it worked which is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As P.Salmon said don't use DELIMITER

Use only

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updateProductPrice`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `list_events`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.caption <> OLD.caption
    THEN
      SET NEW.caption = 1;
  END IF ;
END
```

as content for your string variable.

Comment: It worked! I just remove the Delimeter as you told me, I'm getting syntax Error on my Workbench but in my VB.NET Application it worked which is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: That is actually a lzlle mro complicated, when you are in a query window you neeed the DELIMITER, but wiorkbench ha  special window for stpred procedure where youdon't need them, you get there from schem- databaseon the left site